# QT painting to widget

Tags: qt, paint, qt5

I'm learning QT5 for fun, and I'm learning about painting to widgets for a 2d game. I've been looking through lots of tutorials and documentation, and want to get some input on where to research from here.

From what I've learned, it seems like painting can only be done in the paintEvent function. I'm trying to figure out how make it so that I can conditionally paint something on a widget depending on keyboard input. For example, I want to make it print "alpha" if I press a, and "beta" if I press b.

Obviously I could do this by a global string variable, but what would some other ways be? I'm looking for the proper QT way to do this, any suggestions? How would you implement the following psudocode?

```
void paintEvent(QPaintEvent*)
{
  QPainter painter(this);

  //painter.drawText(QPoint(100,100), "example");

 }


void keyPressEvent( QKeyEvent *k )
{
    QString temp = k->text();

    if(temp == "a") 
        //paint "alpha"
    if(temp == "b")
        //paint "beta"
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `QGraphicsScene`. It's more high level than `paintEvent`, it has many convenient abilities and should be used if you want to paint something that is not entirely trivial.

For example, in your case you need to store `QGraphicsTextItem* text_item` variable as a class member. In the initialization you do the following:

```
text_item = scene->addText("initial text");
```

When you decided to change text, simply use this object:

```
text_item->setPlainText("new_text");
```

Graphics view framework will repaint appropriate area for you.

This is not a complete example. You need to add a view to your widget and initialize a scene to get this work. Please refer to the [Graphics View Framework](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/graphicsview.html) page for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You're pretty much there. You'd use a member variable, not a global. I'd write your keypress method like this:

```
class MyWidget : public QWidget {
    protected:
        void paintEvent(QPaintEvent*);
        void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent*);
    private:
        QString mText;
};

...

void MyWidget::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *k) {
    if(k->key() == Qt::Key_A)
        mText = "alpha";
    else if(k->key() == Qt::Key_B)
        mText = "beta";

    update();
}
```

Using `key()` is going to be a lot safer than magic string comparisons.

Comment: Really? It makes sense but seems a bit too workaround-ish. What about using a QPixmap?

Do I have to actively store in variables everything I want it to paint in paintEvent?

Comment: I'm not sure what a QPixmap is going to do for you in this example. And yes you need to maintain state separately from your paint event. It will get called many times automatically by Qt's painting system and you'll need to know the state of your widget at any given time, not just at keyPress time.

Comment: This seems rather inefficent. Is there any way I could have the paint area remain static between calls to paintEvent?

Comment: (Thanks for your answer, I'm just trying to figure out the programming environment better :) )

Comment: It is not inefficient. This is one way to get things done (a good way too)

Comment: The bottom line is there are many reasons Qt may decide your widget needs to repaint, even if its state doesn't change. Thus you have to maintain state between keyPressEvents.